# Django: How to load initial data for a foreignkey field

Tags: django

I'm trying to create some initial data with Django fixtures. Now my model has a field with `ForeignKey` to another model. How how can I handle this in the `json` file

```
[
  {
    "model":"src.Pricing",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      ...
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    "model":"src.PricingFeature",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      ...
      "pricing": "",
      ...
    }
  }
]
```

The second one has field called **pricing**, and the is supposed to be an instance of `src.Pricing` *(the first dictionary in the list)*. How can I get the instance and pass it

Answer (score 0):

You juste have to provide the `ID` of the foreignkey instance :

```
[
  {
    "model":"src.Pricing",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
    ...
    ...
    }
  },
 {
   "model":"src.PricingFeature",
   "pk": 1,
   "fields": {
   ...
   "pricing": 1,
   ...
   }
 }
]
```

**Note :** But be sure that the `id` of the foreignkey exist (if it's not nullable)